# c# - search a string array using strings from another string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, search

Just like in the title. I got one array of strings and second array of strings. I want to display result in this kind of pattern: first element of the first array - then all elements from second array that occurs in first element of first array. After that second element of first array and all elements from second array that occurs in second element of first array. And so on.
For example:

```
string[] arrayA = {"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, justo", "notgin like good cold beer"};
string[] arrayB = {"justo","beer","lorem"}
for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.Length; i++)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(arrayA[i]);

       for (int j = 0; j < arrayB.Length; j++)
       {
          int controlIndex = arrayA[i].IndexOf(arrayB[j]);
          if (controlIndex != -1)
          {
               Console.Write(" :--contains-->" + arrayB[j]);
          }

    }
```

}

So the result should looks like this:

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, justo :--contains--> **justo,lorem**
- notgin like good cold beer :--contains--> **beer**.

But mine result is:
 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, justo :--contains--> ***justo***
 - notgin like good cold beer :--contains--> **beer**.

So as you can see there is no **lorem listed**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not hard at all if you break your problem down some. First of all, get away from dealing with arrays and indexes into them. Just use `IEnumerable<T>`, it will make your life easier.

Here's how I see it:

First, you want to find all strings from an array `needles`, that are part of a string, `haystack`.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> MatchingStrings(string haystack, IEnumerable<string> needles)
{
    return needles.Where(needle => haystack.Contains(needle));
}
```

This will return an IEnumerable of all of the strings from `needles` that are a part of `haystack`.

Then, you want to simply iterate over all of your search strings, I'll call that `haystacks`.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var haystacks = new[] {
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, justo",
            "notgin like good cold beer"
        };

        var needles = new[] {"justo", "beer", "lorem"};

        foreach (var haystack in haystacks) {
            Console.Write(haystack + "  contains --> ");
            var matches = MatchingStrings(haystack, needles);

            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", matches));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Note that `String.Contains()` is **case-sensitive**. So "Lorem" will not match "lorem". If you want this behavior, you will have to convert them to lowercase first.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> MatchingStringsCaseInsensitive(string haystack, IEnumerable<string> needles)
{
    var h = haystack.ToLower();
    return needles.Where(needle => h.Contains(needle.ToLower()));
}
```

Comment: This is good but will also return something like this LoremTy which is not good. Should only return when there is a "Lorem".

Comment: You never specified that it was by words.  One should be able to modify this however, using `String.Split` to split each haystack by spaces, into words, and searching those.

Comment: There always is! That's why it's fun. Remember to accept one of the answers if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] arrayA = {"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, justo", "notgin like good cold beer"};
string[] arrayB = {"justo","beer","lorem"};

foreach (var s in arrayA)
{
    Console.Write(s + " contains: " +
                  string.Join(",", arrayB.Where(s.Contains)));
}
```

And if you want to ignore case:

```
foreach (var s in arrayA)
{
    Console.Write(s + " contains: " +
                  string.Join(",", arrayB.Where(x =>
                      s.IndexOf(x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1)));
}
```

Comment: Nice :). I really need to use lambda expressions. But after thinking my code was good (i made a mistake with capital Lorem so thats why it hasnt been listed). Thank you any way.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var a in arrayA)
{
    Console.WriteLine("a: " + a);
    Console.WriteLine("bs: " + 
        String.Join(", ", arrayB.Where(b => a.IndexOf(b) > -1)));
}
```

Also if you mean to not care about case, `a.IndexOf(b)` would be `a.IndexOf(b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`.

Comment: No need for `.ToArray()` in .net 4 ;)

Comment: @YoryeNathan thank you, too used to 3.5. I wish they'd add that same overload to the string constructor.

Comment: What do you mean, like `new string(myIEnumerable)`? What would be the idea?

Comment: @YoryeNathan `new string(IEnumerable<char>)`. Simplest example is reversing a string. If that constructor existed you could do `new string(myString.Reverse())`.

Comment: Why not just having a Reverse method on string that returns a reversed string?

Comment: @YoryeNathan that extension would be ambiguous with the LINQ one. But that's just an example, I think I've had other uses for this.

Comment: You can always make an extension method `string ToString(this IEnumerable<char> source)` which won't be ambiguous.

Comment: @YoryeNathan True. I figure since the `new string(char[])` is there, why not add it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Linq solution:

```
var result = arrayA.Select(a => new{
    A = a,
    bContains = arrayB.Where(b => a.IndexOf(b, 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)            
});

foreach(var x in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:--contains-->{1}", x.A, string.Join(",", x.bContains));
}
```

Here's a demo: http://ideone.com/wxl6I

Comment: Why use anonymous types when you don't really have to?

Comment: @YoryeNathan: Because i don't know the desired result, it might be a `Console.WriteLine`, it might be an array,list,class or tuple. So i've created the most dynamic thing, so that OP can use it to create what he want.

Comment: But you do know the desired result - he wants to print them. He even wants it in a very specific way. Looks like there isn't much more to it.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: And my solution does exactly that without extra work. But that might be a simplification to illustrate the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt

```
string[] arrayA = {"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, justo", "notgin like good cold beer"};
string[] arrayB = {"justo", "beer", "lorem"};

foreach (var item in from a in arrayA from b in arrayB where a.Contains(b) select new {a, b})
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.a);
    Console.WriteLine(item.b);
}
```

Note: `Contains` is a case sensitive compare and you'll need to write a custom comparer (as other answers have already done)

Answer (score 0):

Lorem is capitalized.  Try using a case-insensitive search:  `.indexOf(string, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`

Answer (score 0):

I have given you all the possible answers , but the contains method will create a problem that it will also return true in the case as below mentioned.

```
reference_string = "Hello Stack Overflow"
test_string = "Over"
```

so try to avoid contains because contains method will

**"Returns a value indicating whether the specified System.String object occurs within the this string"**

Note: the StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase is added for case insensitive.

```
/// <summary>
        /// Compares using binary search
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input"> search input</param>
        /// <param name="reference"> reference string</param>
        /// <returns> returns true or false</returns>
        public bool FatMan(string input, string reference)
        {
            string[] temp = reference.Split();
            Array.Sort(temp);
            List<string> refe = new List<string> { };
            refe.AddRange(temp);

            string[] subip = input.Split();
            foreach (string str in subip)
            {
                if (refe.BinarySearch(str, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// compares using contains method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input"> search input</param>
        /// <param name="reference"> reference string</param>
        /// <returns> returns true or false</returns>
        public bool Hiroshima(string input, string reference)
        {
            string[] temp = reference.Split();
            Array.Sort(temp);
            List<string> refe = new List<string> { };
            refe.AddRange(temp);
            string[] subip = input.Split();

            foreach (string str in subip)
            {
                if (!refe.Contains(str, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }


        public bool Nakashaki(string input, string reference)
        {
            string[] temp = reference.Split();
            Array.Sort(temp);
            List<string> refe = new List<string> { };
            refe.AddRange(temp);
            string[] subip = input.Split();

            int result = (from st in subip where temp.Contains(st, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) select st).Count();

            if (result <= 0)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// compares using contains method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input"> search input</param>
        /// <param name="reference"> reference string</param>
        /// <returns> returns true or false</returns>
        public bool LittleBoy(string input, string reference)
        {
            string[] subip = input.Split();
            foreach (string str in subip)
            {
                if (!reference.Contains(str))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 bool oupt ;
 string[] strarray1 = new string[3]{"abc","def","ghi" };
 string[] strarray2 = new string[4] { "648", "888", "999", "654" };
 if (strarray1.All(strarray.Contains))
    oupt = true;
 else
    oupt = false;
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO ! Please add a few lines along your code to explain why you think your answer is a good solution to the original question, thanks.